# MySQL - How to compare varchar decimals returned from CASE WHEN?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, decimal, varchar, case-when

I have a sql that I wish to sort by `country` first, then each `country` has its own sorting rules.

Here is my sql:

```
select country, state, creditLimit, salesRepEmployeeNumber, customerNumber from customers
order by field(country, 'UK', 'france', 'USA') desc,
(
case when country = 'USA' then state
    when country = 'UK' then salesRepEmployeeNumber
    when country  = 'france' then creditLimit
    else customerNumber
end
);
```

The problem is, `creditLimit` is of type `decimal`. But it looks like `case when` converted `decimal` to `varchar`, and `creditLimit` is compared as `varchar`s:

```
118200.00
123900.00
 21000.00
 53800.00
 61100.00
 65000.00
 68100.00
 77900.00
 81100.00
 82900.00
 84300.00
 95000.00
```

I thought about casting the varchars back to decimal, but when it is not France, they should not be compared as decimals.

How to fix this? Also how could I sort France's decimalLimit in descending order?

Comment: When doing custom ordering like this, I have a habit of "seeing" my order list first before putting it in the `ORDER BY`. What I'm saying is that you can put the `CASE` statement from `ORDER BY` to `SELECT` then assign it with an alias and use the alias to replace the `CASE` statement in the `ORDER BY`. That way you can see how the ordering is and adjust from the `CASE` statement in `SELECT`.

Comment: @tcadidot0 This advice is very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are trying to sort by a single `CASE` expression, but sometimes you want to use a text column, and sometimes you want to use a decimal column.  You *can't* make `state` decimal, but you can make a decimal text.  So, one approach here would be to convert the `creditLimit` decimal column to text and also left pad it with zeroes, so that it sorts properly as text:

```sql
SELECT country, state, creditLimit, salesRepEmployeeNumber,
       customerNumber
FROM customers
ORDER BY
    FIELD(country, 'UK', 'france', 'USA') DESC,
    CASE country WHEN 'USA'    THEN state
                 WHEN 'UK'     THEN salesRepEmployeeNumber
                 WHEN 'france' THEN LPAD(creditLimit, 13, '0')
                 ELSE customerNumber END;
```